# index not defined error in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, usps

I copied some PHP I wrote a while back to scrub addresses.  In the original page, it lives on a live webserver and works perfectly.  The current script runs from the command line on my development machine.  the CLI script always throws 'index not defined' errors, but the index is defined, from this code:

```
$url = 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=ZipCodeLookup&XML=';
$msg = '
<ZipCodeLookupRequest USERID="xxxxxxxxxx">
<Address ID="0"><FirmName></FirmName><Address1>' . $suite . '</Address1>
<Address2>' . $street . '</Address2>
<City>' . $city . '</City><State>' . $state . '</State>
</Address></ZipCodeLookupRequest>
';

//get the response from the USPS
$newurl = $url . urlencode($msg);

// echo $newurl;

$xml    = $newurl;
$parser = xml_parser_create();

// open a file and read data
$fp      = fopen($xml, 'r');
$xmldata = fread($fp, 4096);

xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xmldata, $values);

xml_parser_free($parser);
//echo $xmldata;
//print_r($values);

if ($values[6][tag] === 'ZIP4') {
    $street = $values[2][value];
    $city   = $values[3][value];
    $state  = $values[4][value];
    $zip5   = $values[5][value];
    $zip4   = $values[6][value];
}
else if ($values[7][tag] === 'ZIP4') {
    $suite  = $values[2][value];
    $street = $values[3][value];
    $city   = $values[4][value];
    $state  = $values[5][value];
    $zip5   = $values[6][value];
    $zip4   = $values[7][value];
}
else {
    $suite  = '';
    $street = '';
    $city   = '';
    $state  = '';
    $zip5   = '';
    $zip4   = '';
}
;

if ($values[2][tag] != 'ERROR') {
    $verifiedBlock = ("
    $suite . chr(13) . chr(10);
    $street . chr(13) . chr(10);
    $city $state $zip5 $zip4
    ");
}
else {
    $verifiedBlock = ("
    The address could not be verified
    ");
}
;
```

If I do a print_r of $values, I get back this:

```
Array (    [0] => Array
       (
           [tag] => ZIPCODELOOKUPRESPONSE
           [type] => open
           [level] => 1
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [tag] => ADDRESS
           [type] => open
           [level] => 2
           [attributes] => Array
               (
                   [ID] => 0
               )

       )

   [2] => Array
       (
           [tag] => ADDRESS1
           [type] => complete
           [level] => 3
           [value] => FL 7
       )
```

etc - I have confirmed that [6] and [7] always exist.  Yet, always it throws 'index not defined' errors on these lines and the `if ($values[2][tag] != 'ERROR')` line.

Can someone please tell me what stupid, obvious thing I'm missing here?

Comment: instead of `$values[2][tag]` try `$values[2]['tag']`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code I see `$values[2][tag]`.In this context `tag` is a constant that must not be defined. You've got key `tag` that is a string, so you have to use it as string, e.g. `$values[2]['tag']`. Oh, and do the same thing with other indexes (keys).

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh (PLB too, of course) - Perfect! I knew it was something obvious.  That didn't occur to me because the code I recycled doesn't have the keys in quotes and it's never been a problem. Thanks so, so much - if I hadn't gotten it today, I would have started entering 4000-odd addresses one by one.

Answer (score 1):

change it to :

```
if ($values[2]["tag"] != 'ERROR')
```